# How to put text inside a rectangle in Manim Community

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, manim, algorithm-animation

[this is the thing I wanted to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCzpY.jpg)

I'm very new to manim I'm trying to put the text inside a rectangle like given in the image
How can I do that ?? :(

Answer (score 9):

You can use `VGroup` to group a box and a text together.

Example Code:

```
from manimlib import *

def create_textbox(color, string):
    result = VGroup() # create a VGroup
    box = Rectangle(  # create a box
        height=2, width=3, fill_color=color, 
        fill_opacity=0.5, stroke_color=color
    )
    text = Text(string).move_to(box.get_center()) # create text
    result.add(box, text) # add both objects to the VGroup
    return result


class TextBox(Scene):  
    def construct(self):

        # create text box
        textbox = create_textbox(color=BLUE, string="Hello world")
        self.add(textbox)

        # move text box around
        self.play(textbox.animate.shift(2*RIGHT), run_time=3)
        self.play(textbox.animate.shift(2*UP), run_time=3)
        self.wait()
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `square.surround(my_text)`:

```
# Test.py
# Manim Community v0.17.1
from manim import *

class Test(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        square = Square(color=WHITE)
        my_text = Text("2020", font_size=48, color=BLUE_D)
        square.surround(my_text)
        self.add(square, my_text)
        self.wait(2)
```

To run it: `manim -pqk -r 1920,1080 test.py Test`

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

You simply define the rectangle's width and height according to the text's properties :

```
txt = Text("Source")
txtbox = Rectangle(width=s.width, height=s.height)
```

To set the padding between the text and the "border", you can add a certain value to either width or height like `width = s.width + 1`.

Answer (score -1):

Writing a text inside a rectangle can be achieved in few steps:

1. Importing manim
2. Write the text to be inside the shape (I am using Rectangle as an example)
3. Animate or create an image.

```
from manim import *

class TextInsideRec(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        text = Text("I am the text to be inside the rectangle")
# To make the text bigger, you can scale it.
        text.scale(1.5)

        text_high = text.height          # getting the text height
        text_width = text.width          # Getting the text width
       
        rec = Rectangle(
            height=text_height +0.5,    # Adding a small space between text and rectangle side
            width=text_width + 0.5,
            color=RED_A,                # Coloring the rectangle
            stroke_width = 12,          # Changing the stroke width
            stroke_color=ORANGE
            )
# Animate it with play or render it as a image with add 
        self.play(Write(text), 
                     Write(rec), run_time = 3)) # run_time is the how long the animation will last
           self.wait(2)
# You can remove at the end if you want to 
                 self.play(Unwrite(t, reverse=False),
                  Uncreate(rec, reverse=True, remover=True))
        self.wait(2)
```

Note: adding wait at the end will ensure the animate will complete, otherwise you will see something left.